# How do I detect a 2 surrounded by 1's in an array? (Python)

Tags: python, arrays

Let's say I have an array containing 1's and 2's. I want to detect the 2's surrounded by 1's and return a count of how many groups of 2's completely surrounded by 1's are present in the array. For example, let's say I have a 20 by 5 array

```
[ 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2
  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2
  1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 2
  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ]
```

So, in the above group, the final count should be "3" because there are 3 groups of 2's that are completely surrounded by 1's [Here is the groups of 2's that I would want included](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXK2X.jpg). The groups of 2's on the edges should not be included because they are not completely surrounded by 1's.

I'm new to working with arrays, so I'm not sure how to handle this problem. How could I go about coding something like this?

Comment: Is this supposed to be a numpy array? Doesn't it put `[]` around each row?

Comment: I keep editing the question to format the array. Why do you keep undoing it?

Comment: I apologize. I was attempting to fix it. Didn't realize you were also working on it.

Comment: Should you expect 4 groups of 2's? I see 4 groups of 2's (one of size 1, assuming 20x5 as you said) in this snippet

Comment: @ee-4-me I have added an image highlighting the groups I would like included in the final count

Comment: This is similar (needing some modification) to this question on Leet Code: https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-islands/. If unfamiliar with Leet Code, you can sort the solutions by most votes and your language of choice to see a good starting place for your particular problem

Comment: Your depiction of your array is nonsensical. Are these sub arrays? How is 'the edge' defined? Are these Numpy arrays? Please post data elements that can be used as an example if you want reasonable answers.

Comment: @ee-4-me thank you for the link on Leet Code. It has been very helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily solve this with regex.

1. convert each row to a string,
2. match '1(2){2,}1' - `#2 or more "2" surrounded by "1"`
3. add match count to total count
4. return

```
def groups(data:list, cols:int, wrap:str='1', find:str='2') -> int:
    expr = __import__('re').compile(fr'{wrap}({find}){{2,}}{wrap}').finditer
    cnt  = 0
    
    for row in range(0, len(data), cols):
        cmp  = ''.join(map(str, data[row:row+cols])) #convert row to string
        cnt += sum(1 for _ in expr(cmp))             #count regex matches
        
    return cnt
    
data = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2,
        2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2,
        2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2,
        1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ]
    
print(groups(data, 20)) #4
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not stated in your question but, since you are expecting the result to be 3 (not 4), we have to assume that you only want groups of 2s that have more than one 2 (i.e. 1,2,1 doesn't count).

You can convert the rows to strings, strip the trailing 2s and count the occurrences of "122" (which corresponds to the start of a group)

```
L = [ [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
      [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
      [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
      [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2],
      [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] ]

sum( "".join(map(str,r)).rstrip("2").count("122") for r in L)

# 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Especially if your array is large, you can treat it as an image of islands (2s) in an ocean of 1s.

Now you can use *"Connected Components Analysis"* to find the islands - see scikit-image [label](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.label).

Then you can do an *"EdgeOut"* a.k.a. *"External Gradient"* morphology to find the pixels around the islands that would be affected by a dilation and check they are all 1s.